# Eclipse IDE Error code -13

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, dll

Hey guys I'm having some problems with Eclipse. Here's a screen:
[image]

Here's my error log and .ini:
http://pastebin.com/VZ8pf6s9

I have JDK and JRE version 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 64-bit Eclipse and a 32-bit JRE (in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_45) . They have to match. I suggest you get the 32-bit Eclipse as it's something you unzip rather than uninstall/install.